# How can I implement timeouts in Microsoft Bot Framework SDK 4 Nodejs using the botbuilder-timeout library?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework SDK4 for Node JS to build my bot. I want to use the botbuilder-timeout npm library mentioned here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-timeout , to implement timeouts in my bot. But the code on this site is for SDK 3 of Bot Framework.

Is there a way I can implement timeouts using the botbuilder-timeout library in SDK4. If not this library then is there any other way to timeout SDK4?

Comment: What is your use case? What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: He is probably trying to do what the library is build for :-) "...enable your bot to prompt the user if user is inactive and ultimately end the conversation if no user activity after a defined period of time."

Comment: Related question for .NET: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694197/can-i-use-botbuilder-timeout-with-net-c