# Can I use botbuilder-timeout with .NET/C#?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

Is it possible to use [botbuilder-timeout](https://github.com/User1m/botbuilder-timeout) with .NET?

All references are to Node.js.

I'm using Bot Framework SDK v4.

Comment: That looks like a v3 package

Comment: It's a npm package so you can use it with Angular/React etc. front-end apps. By .net, do you mean you want to use in C# app?

Comment: Yes C# app.....

Comment: No, you cannot use a v4 Bot Framework Node package with v3 bot written in C#. As far as I know, there is not a good alternative for C#.

Comment: Bummer.........